# ASP.NET Application_Error being invoked twice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I use `Application_Error` to handle errors in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. Today I noticed that for one particular error case, this method is called twice: When requesting a resouce with a leading underscore, as e.g. `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

The implementation of `Application_Error` consumes the last server error:

```
var exception = server.GetLastError();
server.ClearError();
...
```

Therefore, when it's called for the second time, `GetLastError` returns `null`. When it's called for the first time, it sets a corresponding status code and content on the response object. The second invocation then caused all these settings to be overwritten. To work around this issue, I now check for a null pointer:

```
if (exception == null) return;
```

This way, it works perfectly fine: The first run of the method replaces the response by an error page and sets the status code. The second run does nothing. Then the response is sent to the client who gets the correct status code and error page.

But this line of code looks like dirty to me. I would prefer to understand what is going on rather than having the error handler quit silently when in fact something must have gone wrong.

Please note: It seems like no exception is thrown anywhere during the first run of the error handling. Otherwise I could understand it. But when debugging it line by line, the whole `Application_Error` method is processed, including an MVC call to a controller and the rendering of the views. In fact, after following gordonml's comment and checking the "Break when CLR exception is thrown" flag, Visual Studio did never break, not even before the first invocation of Application_Error.

Comment: It's possible that it is being called as a result of a secondary request, such as a request for another element on the page, or favicon.ico.  You can force the debugger to break on all exceptions by going to the Debug menu in visual studio and clicking "Exceptions".  From there you can check "Thrown" for "Common language runtime exceptions".  This will catch all exceptions thrown on any thread AFAIK.

Comment: @gordonml: That's not the case. These two invocations of Application_Error happen in the course of processing one single request. Both invocations have the same response object, such that the second invocation can discard anything that the first invocation wrote into the response.

Comment: @cacho - I apologize, this is too long ago to remember. Though if I found the answer I would probably have updated this here.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing happened to me.

My solution was the following ( I don't like it, but I like it better than `if(exception == null) return;` )

In the case that the exception is thrown within an AJAX call to the server, I just removed the `Response.StatusCode = (int)401`.

I had that in the `Global.asax.cs` because sometimes, the API access token expired earlier than the http session. If I set Response.StatusCode = 500, the `Application_Error` does not fire twice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities in your Web.config to define custom errors. Make sure only one of them is present, otherwise the corresponding erros are called twice.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  ...
</httpErrors>


<customErrors mode="On">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
  ...
</customErrors>
```